# Some topological problem on open sets

Tags: general-topology

There is this statement in my topology notes, where it states that:

Denote $\mathbb{R}^n_{+}$ as the upper half surface in $\mathbb{R}^n,$ denoted by $\{(u_1,...,u_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n:u_n\ge0\}$. Then by the subspace topology, $\mathbb{R}^n_{+}$ is open if there exists a set $V^*$ such that $V=V^* \cap \mathbb{R}^n_{+}$, where $V^*\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. It is clear that if $V\subset \mathbb{R}^n_+,$ is a disjoint open subset from the subspace $\{u_n=0\},$ then $V$ is open $\mathbb{R}^n_+,$ **iff** V is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$

What I have trouble seeing here is I get the subspace topology part as it is directly following from the definition of subspace topology. However, I dont understand the last part where it mentions the **iff** part.

Could someone please explain why that is the case?

**EDIT:** Also what is the significance of the set being disjoint to $\{u_n=0\}$ in this case?

Comment: Let $V=\mathbb{R}^n_{+}$.  Then $V$ is certainly open in $\mathbb{R}^n_{+}$ but not in $\mathbb{R}^n$  Think about the upper half plane in  $\mathbb R^2$ if you you still don't see it.

Comment: Could you give me a numerical example? I think I get it, but still cant seem to be assured. For instance why is say $(1,2)$ open in $\mathbb{R}^2_{+}$, but not in $\mathbb{R}^2?$

Comment: What is the subspace $\{u_n=0\}$?.. I think you mean $\{(u_1,...,u_n):\exists j\;(u_j=0)\}.$ .. The letter $n$ is already in use, as the dimension.

Comment: I was not sure as I just took from the notes as written. Could you please clarify what would be the significance of being disjoint to that subspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that in $\mathbb R^n$ a set is open if an only if it contains an $n$-dimensional open ball about each of its points.  Let's look at this in $\mathbb R^2$ and take $\mathbb R^2_+$ to be $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\mid y\ge0\},$ the upper half-plane.  Consider the square $S=\{(x,y)| 2>y>0, -1<x<1\}$  This is open, whether considered as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ or as a subset of $\mathbb R^2_+.$

Now consider the square $\overline S=\{(x,y)| 2>y\ge0, -1<x<1\}.$  This is not an open subset of $\mathbb R^2,$ for it contains no neighborhoods of the points on the $x-$axis.  It is an open subset of $\mathbb R^2_+,$ however, because it is the intersection of $\mathbb R^2_+$ with $\{(x,y)| 2>y>-1, -1<x<1\}$ for instance.

Comment: Thank you for the help. But I am very confused with open sets atm, why doesn't it contain any neighbourhoods of the points on the $x$-axis?